Can we pre-emptively blocklist the [api] tag?
Today I learned that we can request tags be blocked from future use (thanks Blacklist the [oracle] tag).
The api tag has long been a source of contention, ref

Is there an [api] to help burninate this tag?
Is the "api" tag a too broad one, and a candidate for burninating?
Revisiting the [api] tag [duplicate]
Isn't [api] a meta-tag that should be removed? [duplicate]

The tag description itself specifically says not to use it

DO NOT USE. Use specific tags like [google-cloud-platform], [facebook], [amazon-web-services] instead or [api-design] where applicable. Questions asking to recommend or find an API are off-topic.

Yet every day there are more questions asked with this tag.
Can we please blocklist the api tag so it can no longer be used?
This is not a burninate request! It's been made very clear in the linked posts above that removing the api tag would be difficult. All I'm asking is that we stop new / edited questions from using it.

From the description for blocklist-request...

This tag is used in requests for adding one or more tags to the blocklist, preventing them from ever being used again
Blocklisting a tag prevents anyone from ever using that tag on a new question or editing a question without removing it.

this feature should just prevent the tag being used for new / future questions. I understand from the previous burnination requests that removing the api tag entirely would be difficult to achieve and that's not what I'm trying to discuss here.

I'm pretty sure that first we'd need to first burninate the tag. With over 90,000 questions, that's not a quick task.

I'm not asking for burnination and based on the discussion for the [tag:oracle] tag, that didn't appear to be a requirement

No, for Oracle is was renamed, @Phil , so the tag [[tag:oracle]] was removed and then blocked. Unless you are suggesting [[tag:API]] be renamed and then blocked as well? If so, what should it be renamed to?

@ThomA thanks for clarifying but the [tag:blocklist-request] description doesn't mention burnination... "This tag is used in requests for adding one or more tags to the blocklist, preventing them from ever being used again". I could be misunderstanding this feature though

If you look at any completed blocked tags, you'll note that there are no questions with those tags as well. So, if we are to delete and block the tags, what should that tag be replaced with?

From blocklist-request: "Blocklisting a tag prevents anyone from ever using that tag on a new question or editing a question without removing it." That sure makes it sound like removing the tag happens after blocklisting it, not before. Am I wrong? My point is that removal of the tag from everything doesn't have to happen first.

@Makyen this is not a burninate request! How exactly did you come to the conclusion that this is a duplicate?

@Phil You mean the question I closed it against, which its tags indicates is both a burninate request and a blocklist request, while this is just a blocklist request, which is a subset of what that question is asking for?

@Makyen the [tag:blocklist-request] tag was added 5 years after the question was opened. It's never mentioned in the question nor any of the answers and obviously was never acted upon. I'm fine with the duplicate if we can actually get the blocklist request actioned.

Note: As I recall, the current staff-mandated process for even considering blocking a tag is that the tag must first be burninated and removed. If the tag is later recreated, then a blocklist request is permitted. I don't necessarily agree with that, but that's my understanding of the position that SE staff has taken for tag blocklist requests. If you want to not follow that process, then an argument need to be made that directly addresses that position.

@Makyen in that case, the description for blocklist-request is seriously misleading

Yes, I agree that it should be expanded. To do so, I'd need to do research to find where the staff position has been stated, but as I recall, it's been reiterated on at least a few, if not several, premature blocklist requests that were denied by staff due to the tag either never having been burninated and/or not having been recreated.

@Makyen I've updated this post to better reflect what OP originally wanted, and used my [tags] mjolnir to reopen this post. I understand that we currently don't have a process to blocklist before burnination, but this can be a nice first try at getting a process formalized. I've also updated the original post to get rid of the blocklist tag, as it wasn't what was requested there. Do let me know if I've overstepped, and feel free to close it again.

I suspect that just blocking, and not removing, the tag would cause a problem because it would mean edits to questions with the tag [[tag:api]] could not be submitted without removing the tag. That isn't necessarily a bad thing, but could result in an odd UX for those users as they are being denied the submission of an edit, due to the tags, despite not effecting the tags in said edit. Considering the usefulness of the tag is agreed to negligible (at best), "destroying" the tag does seem an ideal as well.

@ThomA IIRC editing a question that has a blocklisted tag just automatically removes the tag when you submit. The only issue is if the question's only tag is [api] but it should show an error message explaining that.

@ThomA the same thing already happens for titles that wouldn't pass the quality filter nowadays, you need to change the title even if you don't modify the title. I don't think it'd be a problem.

This tag should be blocklisted, because it's the only way it can ever be cleaned up. It is too frequently used to have a hope of making a dent in its usage without this.
Ideally, it should also be deleted by staff and replaced with nothing.  It is not merely ambiguous; it conveys no information whatsoever, as nearly all questions on the site involve some API of some sort.  Replacing it with untagged (as deleting the tag would do on questions with no other tags) would not remove any information from those questions.  Simply deleting it would avoid the disruption and pointless toil of editing it out of tens of thousands of questions.

I think [tag:web] is even worse.

"Replacing it with untagged (as deleting the tag would do on questions with no other tags) would not remove any information from those questions." But it would possibly mean suddenly having quite a few such untagged questions instead of only a handful. (Actually, that query is timing out for me at the moment. SEDE really seems to struggle nowadays.)

@Dharman and [tag:frontend] and [tag:backend]

"It is not merely ambiguous; it conveys no information whatsoever" I'd take it a step further and say that it often detracts from information because people use it instead of a real tag that already exists by combining it with others. For example [windows] +[api] for [winapi] or [magento] + [api] to signify they want to use a Wordpress API. That combination is annoying because there are two [magento-rest-api] and [magento-soap-api]. There is also a lot of [rest] + [api] questions that are for neither - the question is about using a specific API not just all REST APIs.

On the "plus" side, though there are over 90,000 questions with the [[tag:api]] tag, only 375 of them only have that tag: SEDE. So there wouldn't be many questions tagged with just [[tag:untagged]].

Why is it showing me that the newest [API] questions are from March 2023 when I click on the tag? Does anyone else see this?

@Laurel because for a while, new questions with the [api] tag have had it removed by community members.

@Dharman <insert "first time?" meme here>

@VLAZ I like that you found out that tags can be actively harmful by preventing good tags from being used. For some reason, that has been impossible for me to explain before (or people just refuses to listen).

How should you tag questions like this one that are about a specific API with no other question about it? Create a single-use [something-api]?

@bfontaine sure. All tags start with one question in them. Note that it's possible other questions also exist about the same thing but none created the tag. So, check if it needs to be applied to more posts. I've gone ahead and created the tag here - there were no other questions for it and also the service seems to be dead for a decade now.
